# Flutter's JustAudio plugin: createTrack returned error -12

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, media-player, just-audio

Here's an error that occurs occasionally and intermittently when using Flutter's justaudio plugin with .m4a audio files;

```
createTrack returned error -12
E/AudioTrack(22346): createTrack_l(8194608): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12 output 0
E/AudioTrack-JNI(22346): Error -12 initializing AudioTrack
D/AudioTrack(22346): gather(): no metrics gathered, track status=-12
E/android.media.AudioTrack(22346): Error code -20 when initializing AudioTrack.
E/IAudioFlinger(22346): createTrack returned error -12
```

The file seems there and clicking play with forward the progress bar but I can't hear anything. If I close and restart Android Studio the problem goes away but it makes me worried about going live. How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, audio players are resource intensive and there are a limited number of them that you can allocate before you get this error. You need to ensure that you dispose of a player once it's no longer being used, before you create new ones, otherwise you'll run out of resources.

Comment: I'm using a PageViewBuilder and thought that I was disposing of each when the page has changed; onPageChanged: (int position) {          
          _pageViewManager.dispose();
          _pageViewManager.playBarNotifier.value  = false;
          _pageViewManager.seturl(audioWidgetProvider.audioname);
        },

Comment: It's also weird that a hot restart won't fix it. Instead, I have to stop and rebuild each time.

Comment: Have you verified for sure that the player is being disposed? For example, inserting a log message at each time you construct a new `AudioPlayer` and each time you dispose it? In the 0.7 version, hot restart would probably cause this problem because that doesn't let the dispose method get called. If you keep hot restarting too many times you would effectively use up all the resources. In the 0.8 release it uses a deprecated FlutterEngine API under the hood to tap into the hot restart event and automatically dispose it for you.